# Thunderbird 5.0 goes offline unbidden

Tags: thunderbird

This message pops up after a few minutes of disuse:

> "You are currently offline. Do you want to go online to get new messages?"

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the magic that detects whether your offline is faulty.

To disable it, open Thunderbird's configuration window (Edit > Preferences or Tools > Options depending on your platform), go to the *Advanced* panel, select the *General* tab, and click *Config Editor*.  In the window that appears, type `toolkit.networkmanager.disable` in the  *filter* box at the top.  Double-click on that option to toggle it to *true*.